# Google Sign-in new login screen missing "create account" option

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-signin, google-client

Recently google changed their UI for sign-in to google application. I have a google sign-in button that in result take user to a page and with use of Google Client PHP API SDK the user is redirected to google sign-in page. The problem I just noticed is that it is missing "create account" button or option. If you directly go to sign-in page from google, like `google.com -> sign in`, it shows "more options" in left bottom corner. But if I do this from my application, the "more options" button is missing.

Is there any way to make it appear? This is quite inconvienient for people who does not yet have google account. They get to sign-in page and there's nothing they can do from that point, if they don't already have google account.

Is there any parameter I should use when using `GoogleClient::createAuthUrl()` to enable creating accounts? Or any other way to configure it?

Comment: I was only making the point that if Google was only one of several options, then bringing back the create account screen wouldn't be important because users were unlikely to use it anyway (for the reasons I described) . If I had to guess I'd say that's probably why Google appear to have removed it. But if you're requiring Google login, then you have more of a problem. I can't see anything in the API setup options that would control something like this. You might have to provide your own link alongside your login button or something.

Comment: Well, this is kind of bad, I only just found out about this. Do you know of any kind of forum of support contact that I could ask about this? I seem to have problem finding anything..

Comment: There are some links at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/identity/ which might of use, I guess. Looks like there's a forum there. But I don't know any more than you could find by searching anyway, sorry.

Comment: Apparently the forum is announcement-only now. Thank you anyway. I did include `google-oauth` tag, since they say they monitor Stack Overflow with this tag.

Comment: that's a shame, you'll have to see if anyone monitoring that tag picks it up, I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147619/discussion-between-user1970395-and-adyson).